# Getting started with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to getting started with Magento 1.9 as a developer. I supposed that Magento had a GitHub repository that I can download the source base, but I could find it.

Where can I find a documentation explaning how to build Magento and setup it on a developer enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install magento , go to the magento official site , open download, search the latest version of magento 1.x ( now it is 1.3.10) . Download zip , unzip it apache2 web server directory ( example var/www/m2). 
Go to apache2 folder, open sites-avaliable , copy 000.default.conf file, rename it to mage.test.conf(name of yours url), in this file change pathes to yours. After go to etc, open file hosts, add new host with the next info , if it is localhost use : 127.0.0.1 mage.test. 
Then if open terminal and insert 
sudo a2ensite mage.test.conf
sudo restart service apache2

Go to the mage.test in yours web-browser. And you will see setup wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mirror of what would have been in the Magento 1 github repo:

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror